# Same sku in items of configurable product in order?

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product

An order with a configurable product.

```
foreach  ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
   echo $item->getSku();
}
```

There're two items. But they have same sku! How did happen? And anyway for each item get it own sku (from configurable and its child product)?

Answer (score 3):

In Magento when you add configurable products into cart it would have the same sku as simple product that was actually added. Anyway every product should have its own unique SKU (or it can be generated dynamically for bundle products for example) More info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309098/why-do-magento-configurable-products-have-a-sku)

To avoid this situation you need to use `getAllVisibleItems` method instead. So your code will be

```
foreach  ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
   echo $item->getSku();
}
```

The difference between them is that `getAllVisibleItems()` has an additional check inside the method for every item of an order `!$item->getParentItemId()` It tests if the product in order has a parent product (it will give you a result without simple products for configurable, bundle etc.)

Comment: Thanks. I know about getAllVisibleItems(), but could I modify magento core to show both Skus, or any hack, maybe?

Comment: You seem to be asking a different thing now. The Answer actually covers your Question excellently. Consider accepting it.